# FindInstance function

Tags: equation-solving

I have a question concerning the [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) function. If I write

```
FindInstance[c == 3, {c, l}]
```

I obtain

> {{c -> 3, l -> 33/10 + (8 I)/5}}

Is there any way to obtain l=0? In general, when one wants to solve a system of equations and one of the variables is free (the system is undeterminate compatible), is it possible to assign the value 0 to it?

**EDIT**: I put a clearer example, since this one is causing confusion. Imagine I ask this problem: find a polynomial P of degree 2 such that P(x+1)-P(x)=1.

```
P = a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2;

Q = (P /. x -> x + 1) - P - 1; (* deg Q = 1 *)

FindInstance[CoefficientList[Q, x] == {0, 0}, {a0, a1, a2}]
```

I obtain

> {{a0 -> 33/10 + (8 I)/5, a1 -> 1, a2 -> 0}}

but clearly x also satifies (x+1)-x=1. I want to obtain the most simple solution (that is, the one with a0=0, but notice that I don't know previously that a0 will disappear from the system, so I cannot assign to a0 the value 0 a priori).

Comment: Maybe my idea is wrong, but the way you write the code, the variables are effectively uninitialized, why should it give a zero, what would the idea behind that argument be --- assign zero to `l`?

Comment: I wrote here an example, but my original problem is slightly different. I have a code that returns a vector (u_0,...u_n). The vector is computed by means of a linear system A(u_0,...u_n)=0, which may not have a unique solution. There are cases that, when I apply A, a u_i disappears from all the equations (in my example, it's as if u_i were l). I would like then to put the value 0 to u_i in such a case, and not a strange complex value 33/10 + (8 I)/5.

Comment: The example I posted is just that, an example. I am asking what one can do in general when there are free variables in the system but you don't know which are.

Comment: If you know that you want to to be zero, just equate it to zero. `FindInstance[{c == 3, a == 0}, {c, a}]` evaluates to `{{c -> 3, a -> 0}}`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you for answering. But my doubt is that, in general, when I have an undeterminate compatible system, I don't know which will be the free variables, so I cannot assign a priori the value 0 to them.

Comment: Recommend that you edit your question to include a minimal working example of an "undeterminate compatible system".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be to restate the problem as a minimization problem, for instance:

```
Minimize[(c - 3)^2 + l^2, {c, l}]
```

returns `{0, {c -> 3, l -> 0}}`.

Another possibility is to use Solve directly:

```
Solve[CoefficientList[Q, x] == 0, {a0, a1, a2}]
{{a1 -> 1, a2 -> 0}}
```

This also returns a warning, that `Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables` but this is, of course, what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
p[x_] = a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2;

eqn = p[x + 1] - p[x] == 1;
```

If you want only real values, restrict `FindInstance` to the real domain.

```
FindInstance[ForAll[x, eqn], {a0, a1, a2}, Reals, 10]

(*  {{a0 -> -(433/10), a1 -> 1, a2 -> 0}, {a0 -> -(207/5), a1 -> 1, 
  a2 -> 0}, {a0 -> -37, a1 -> 1, a2 -> 0}, {a0 -> -26, a1 -> 1, 
  a2 -> 0}, {a0 -> 109/10, a1 -> 1, a2 -> 0}, {a0 -> 84/5, a1 -> 1, 
  a2 -> 0}, {a0 -> 92/5, a1 -> 1, a2 -> 0}, {a0 -> 139/5, a1 -> 1, 
  a2 -> 0}, {a0 -> 43, a1 -> 1, a2 -> 0}, {a0 -> 97/2, a1 -> 1, 
  a2 -> 0}}  *)
```

Or, more generally,

```
soln = Reduce[ForAll[x, eqn], {a0, a1, a2}] // ToRules

(*  {a1 -> 1, a2 -> 0}  *)

eqn /. soln

(*  True  *)
```

To set any arbitrary variables (a0 in this case) to zero

```
soln2 = {soln,
    Thread[
     Complement[{a0, a1, a2}, soln[[All, 1]]] -> 0]} // 
  Flatten // Sort

(*  {a0 -> 0, a1 -> 1, a2 -> 0}  *)
```